# How to intercept log messages from Quarkus/Camel for testing purposes?

Tags: testing, apache-camel, quarkus

I'm building a Java application with Quarkus/Camel which generates some logstatements here and there. I want to be able to verify if the correct logstatements are generated so I have a need to intercept the logmessages. The problem is that I have a logtemplate specified in the Quarkus application.properties file, but this template is not used when running tests. As a result, I cannot verify the correctness of the logstatements.
I have tried to copy the logtemplate to the testbranch but it is nog picked up by Quarkus. Does somebody know how I can pursuade my tests to use the proper logtemplate?

Comment: Please provide some code to get help.